# Пунктуация в предложении со словом «вон»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, частица

*Раньше вон панки были, тоже было плевать на нормы общества.*
Нужно ли в этом случае перед словом "вон" или после него ставить запятую?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы оформила это предложение так (без запятой, но с тире; смущает, правда, повтор: были — было):
*Раньше вон панки были — тоже было плевать на нормы общества.*

Считаю, что [**вон**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD) здесь является частицей.

> **2.** Употребляется для уточнения и усиления значения последующего слова или высказывания в целом; вот. *Вон какой сильный! Вон как поранился! Вон сколько мы не виделись!*

*...и Вовочка слышал, как он бормочет: «Говно народ. Раз в тысячу лет, может, выпадает такое... Раньше **вон** душу за это продавали, а теперь — отпустите да отпустите...»* (Андрей Лазарчук. Сентиментальное путешествие на двухместной машине времени).

*— Да ты не спеши, раньше **вон** всякую гадость прибрать нужно, какие там ящики! — улыбнулся Ветковский* (Антон Макаренко. Педагогическая поэма).